# RDS - PLC wires

Tags: plc, io, reference

I'm an American but I'm changing some of my drawings to RDS (Reference Designation System) to make these drawings more similar to the drawings of equipment that keep coming in.

What is the proper designation for PLC input and output with RDS? Since 'X' is defined as a connection, what do label IO terminals?

Answer (score 0):

Since the PLC input card is already designated by the manufacturer, you should use whatever designation that is. Avoid labeling ambiguous or confusing information between your drawings and the physical hardware. For example, a Siemens ET200 digital input card is marked DI1, DI2, DI3, DI4, LC, M etc. for in-cabinet. If you have on machine input blocks you could label them X#.(pin number)

This will greatly depend on your assembly and hardware. Siemens and Rockwell PLC cards have some example drawings for references depending on their products. If you are using different brands of IO cards then your IO terminal designations would not necessarily match across the board. Although these are typically conventional among the top brands.

Can you upload an example of the IO terminal you are using to make this answer more accurate?

Comment: Are you actually familiar with the RDS standard and speaking from that, or is this your general practice.   The reason I ask, is because the RDS is new to me.